# loading status change after fetch data completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have action creator to get data from API and have another action creator for loading status and want change loading status when data completely fetched.

Now, I wrote following codes but not working good, Loading status changes to false before data fetched completely.

My ActionCreator:

```
export const loadingStatus = (bool) => {
    return {
        type: Constants.LOADING_STATUS,
        isLoading: bool
    };
}
const allFlashCards = (action) => {
    return{
        type: Constants.ALL_CARD,
        ...action
    }
};

export const fetchAllFlashCards = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loadingStatus(true));
        return axios.post(API.DISPLAY_ALL_CARDS)
            .then((data)=>{
                console.warn(data);
                dispatch(allFlashCards(data));
                dispatch(loadingStatus(false));
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.warn(error)
            });
    }
};
```

and my Reducer:

```
const FlashCard = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Constants.ADD_CARD:
            return {...state, data: action.data};
            break;
        case Constants.ALL_CARD:
            return {...state, data: action};
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const Loading = (status= false, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Constants.LOADING_STATUS:
            return action.isLoading;
            break;
        default:
            return status;
    }
}
```

and in my component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCards();
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            {this.props.loading ?
                    <Loading/> :
                    Object.keys(this.props.cards.data).map(this.renderCard)
                }
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    cards: state.main,
    loading: state.loading
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchCards: bindActionCreators(fetchAllFlashCards, dispatch)
});
```

and combineReducer is:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import FlashCard , { Loading } from './FlashCard.js';
import { routerReducer } from "react-router-redux";

export default combineReducers({
    main: FlashCard,
    loading: Loading,
    routing: routerReducer
});
```

In my page, I have an error in console and it's:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` and if put my codes in timeout fixed my bug :/

What should i do?

Comment: what is state.main?

Comment: combineReducer added in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed my problem:

In my actionCreator change fetchAllFlashCards method to following:

```
export const fetchAllFlashCards = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loadingStatus(true));
        return axios.post(API.DISPLAY_ALL_CARDS)
            .then(({data})=>{
                dispatch(allFlashCards(data));
                dispatch(loadingStatus(false));
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.warn(error)
            });
    }
};
```

and in reducer change FlashCard reducer to following:

```
const FlashCard = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Constants.ADD_CARD:
            return {...state, data: action.data};
            break;
        case Constants.ALL_CARD:
            return {...state, data: action.data};
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your default state is wrong here:

```
const FlashCard = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case Constants.ADD_CARD:
            return {...state, data: action.data};
            break;
        case Constants.ALL_CARD:
            return {...state, data: action};
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

It should be an empty object `{}` instead of an empty array `[]`, since you're returning objects.

This code

```
export const fetchAllFlashCards = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loadingStatus(true));
        return axios.post(API.DISPLAY_ALL_CARDS)
            .then((data)=>{
                console.warn(data);
                dispatch(allFlashCards(data));
                dispatch(loadingStatus(false));
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.warn(error)
            });
    }
};
```

Looks completely fine. `loadingStatus(false)` should not be called before setting the flash cards. Your reducers and action creators are synchronous (as they should). So, nothing of note there.

I saw that you're using `action.data` on the `Constants.ADD_CARD` action case, but in your code you do not dispatch any actions with that type. Do you do it somewhere else? Maybe that's where the error is?

EDIT:

Another place that you're using `.data` is in your renderer: `this.props.cards.data`. What's the value of the `state.main`?
How are you creating your rootReducer? It should be something like this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  main: FlashCard,
  loading: Loading,
});
```

Are you using `main` there? Or maybe `cards`?

Comment: I'm not using it right now but use it after fix this bug.

Comment: Your problem could be on the rootReducer creation. Check the edit, please?

Comment: I import routerReducer from react-router-redux

Comment: I think I should false loading after completely fetched data

Comment: so... Where do you state that `main` is using the result of the `FlashCard` reducer?

Comment: I don't understand your purpose.

Comment: saw your edit. It looks ok. Try changing your render function to not use `this.props.cards` but only log its value to the console to see what's actually there. Maybe the value is not being stored on the reducer in the way you're expecting it to?

Comment: if write following code working good:
{this.props.loading ?
                        <Loading/> :
                        setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.props.cards.data)},1000)
                    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163847/discussion-between-omid-and-sergio-moura).

Comment: Don't have any comment?